# Inner join returning more results even after excluding parameters

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

My actuall query is:

```
SELECT rrr.extern_OD_id,
   rrr.refund_it_amount,
   rrr.refund_amount,
   rrr.invoice_ref_7,
   rrr.invoice_total_amount
FROM
(SELECT return.extern_OD_id,
      return.refund_it_amt AS refund_it_Amount,
                              return.refund_amount,
                              billing_tbl.invoice_ref_7,
                              billing_tbl.invoice_total_amount
FROM
 (SELECT rrrf.extern_OD_id,
         sum(rrrf.refund_it_amt) AS refund_it_amt,
         sum(rrrf.refund_amount/100)   refund_amount
  FROM rrr__refunds_fact rrrf
  WHERE rrrf.refund_status = 'completed'
    AND rrrf.refund_created_date_key >= '20150401'
    AND rrrf.refund_mode IN('CREDIT_CARD',
                            'CREDIT_EMI',
                            'DDCHEQUE',
                            'DEBIT_CARD',
                            'GIFT_VOUCHER',
                            'ICICI',
                            'NETBANKING',
                            'back_to_source')
    AND rrrf.refund_mode NOT IN ('GIFT_Card')
    GROUP BY rrrf.extern_OD_id) RETURN
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT invoice_ref_7,
         sum(invoice_total_amount) invoice_total_amount
  FROM invoice_fact
  WHERE invoice_type_key = 'receiv_note'
    AND invoice_status_key NOT IN('voided',
                                  'canceled',
                                  'cancelled')
 GROUP BY invoice_ref_7) billing_tbl ON RETURN.extern_OD_id =billing_tbl.invoice_ref_7
WHERE RETURN.refund_amount <> billing_tbl.invoice_total_amount
 OR billing_tbl.invoice_ref_7 IS NULL) rrr
WHERE rrr.refund_it_amount >0
AND rrr.refund_amount >0
```

But when I try to join another table and exclude some parameters, it gives me more records than records from table srrr__refunds_fact.
It gives many records from the new joined table i.e. Payment_TBL which are not present in rrr__refunds_fact. 
Can you please tell me where I am going wrong.
As per my understanding if the first query is returning n records, after joining the new records should be n or < n

```
SELECT rrr.extern_OD_id,
   rrr.refund_it_amount,
   rrr.refund_amount,
   rrr.invoice_ref_7,
   rrr.invoice_total_amount
FROM
(SELECT return.extern_OD_id,
      return.refund_it_amt AS refund_it_Amount,
                              return.refund_amount,
                              billing_tbl.invoice_ref_7,
                              billing_tbl.invoice_total_amount
FROM
 (SELECT rrrf.extern_OD_id,
         sum(rrrf.refund_it_amt) AS refund_it_amt,
         sum(rrrf.refund_amount/100)   refund_amount
  FROM rrr__refunds_fact rrrf
  JOIN Payment_TBL paymt ON paymt.payment_ref_num_2 = rrrf.extern_OD_id
  WHERE rrrf.refund_status = 'completed'
    AND rrrf.refund_created_date_key >= '20150401'
    AND rrrf.refund_mode IN('CREDIT_CARD',
                            'CREDIT_EMI',
                            'DDCHEQUE',
                            'DEBIT_CARD',
                            'GIFT_VOUCHER',
                            'ICICI',
                            'NETBANKING',
                            'back_to_source')
    AND rrrf.refund_mode NOT IN ('GIFT_Card')
    AND paymt.payment_method_key NOT IN ('WALLET')
    AND paymt.payment_ref_num_4 NOT IN ('PRICE_REFUND')
   GROUP BY rrrf.extern_OD_id) RETURN
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT invoice_ref_7,
         sum(invoice_total_amount) invoice_total_amount
  FROM invoice_fact
  WHERE invoice_type_key = 'receiv_note'
    AND invoice_status_key NOT IN('voided',
                                  'canceled',
                                  'cancelled')
 GROUP BY invoice_ref_7) billing_tbl ON RETURN.extern_OD_id =billing_tbl.invoice_ref_7
WHERE RETURN.refund_amount <> billing_tbl.invoice_total_amount
 OR billing_tbl.invoice_ref_7 IS NULL) rrr
WHERE rrr.refund_it_amount >0
AND rrr.refund_amount >0
```

Comment: *As per my understanding if the first query is returning n records, after joining the new records should be n or < n* - Not true. You can have up to N*M rows (i.e., Cartesian product), where M is the number of rows in the second table

Comment: ok. But in the above query I am have added condition                                   JOIN Payment_TBL paymt ON paymt.payment_ref_num_2 = rrrf.extern_OD_id. but the output has extern_OD_id which are ont present in payment_ref_num_2 table.